# Disable jQuery function after one click, to prevent multiple executions

Tags: jquery

I have the following function which fetches more comments beyond the 20 that are shown by default:

```
$('.more_comments_link').live('click', function() {
    $(".more_comments_link").text("Fetching More Comments...");

    var ajaxOpts = {
        type: "get",
        url: "ajax_getcomments.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "&itemid=<? echo $id; ?>&type=1&owner=<? echo $event["data"]["e_creator"]; ?>&more=1",
        success: function(data) {
            $('.discussion-more').after(data);
            $(".discussion-more").hide();
        }
    };

    $.ajax(ajaxOpts);
    return false;
});
```

It works, but the only problem is, the user can click the button three times really quickly, and it will send three requests to *ajax_getcomments.php*, getting the same result set every time.

I tried adding

```
$(".more_comments_link").unbind('click');
```

but it doesn't do anything.

The initial result set is also fetched with jQuery, hence I’m using `.live(click'`.

I am not sure if it has anything to do with why it’s not working.

Comment: Where did you place your unbind statement?

Comment: @George regardless, `.unbind('click')` won't work because the listener was bound with `.live()` not `.click()` or `.bind('click')`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`live` doesn't work with `unbind` -- you need [`die`](http://api.jquery.com/die) instead.

**However** there is a better solution. Since you probably want to be able to update the content more than once, you can set a variable to see whether a request is currently running:

```
var requestRunning = false;
$('.more_comments_link').live('click', function () {
    if (requestRunning) { // don't do anything if an AJAX request is pending
        return;
    }

    $(".more_comments_link").text("Fetching More Comments ...");

    var ajaxOpts = {
        type: "get",
        url: "ajax_getcomments.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "&itemid=<? echo $id; ?>&type=1&owner=<? echo $event["
        data "]["
        e_creator "]; ?>&more=1",
        success: function (data) {
            $('.discussion-more').after(data);
            $(".discussion-more").hide();
        },
        complete: function() {
            requestRunning = false;
        }

    };

    requestRunning = true;
    $.ajax(ajaxOpts);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: this is a good solution if you also set requestRunning false when the ajax error.  Without that it will never work after an error.

Answer (score 16):

All of these solutions are far too complex for a very simple solution; use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

Simply change `live` to `one`. See below:

```
$('.more_comments_link').one('click', function() {
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.die()` to unbind `.live()` events.

- [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live)
- [`die`](http://api.jquery.com/die)

Or set a flag elsewhere that says the request is in progress and check that at the beginning of the click handler.

Comment: This works, but I realized lonesomeday's suggestion applies a little better in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$('element').off()
```

This will disable any event of your component that you are listening to.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the disabled keyword. This way you don't have to unbind the function; you just disable it from being pressed:

```
$('.more_comments_link').live('click', function() {
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    $(".more_comments_link").text("Fetching More Comments ...");

    var ajaxOpts = {
        type: "get",
        url: "ajax_getcomments.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "&itemid=<? echo $id; ?>&type=1&owner=<? echo $event["data"]["e_creator"]; ?>&more=1",
        success: function(data) {
            $('.discussion-more').after(data);
            $(".discussion-more").hide();
        }
    };

    $.ajax(ajaxOpts);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, you might not have to use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live), in which case [one](http://api.jquery.com/one) would do exactly what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

My solution, working global on all Ajax requests. If it is the active request, new with the same URL will be aborted. It is working fine.

```
var activeRequests = [];

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, jqxhr, settings) {
    var i = activeRequests.indexOf(settings.url);
    if (i != -1) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            activeRequests.splice(activeRequests.indexOf(settings.url), 1); }, 75);
    }
});

$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, jqxhr, settings) {
    var i = activeRequests.indexOf(settings.url)
    if (i != -1) {
        jqxhr.abort();
        activeRequests.push(settings.url);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.more_comments_link').live('click', function(e) {

    if($(e.target).data('oneclicked')!='yes') {

        $(this).text("Fetching More Comments ...");

        var ajaxOpts = {
            type: "get",
            url: "ajax_getcomments.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "&itemid=<? echo $id; ?>&type=1&owner=<? echo $event["data"]["e_creator"]; ?>&more=1",
            success: function(data) {
                $('.discussion-more').after(data);
                $(".discussion-more").hide();
            }
        };

        $.ajax(ajaxOpts);
        return false;
    }

    $(e.target).data('oneclicked','yes');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use for a single click on a button over the webpage

```
 $('button id or classs').one('click',function(){    
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

For me this worked:

```
$('.more_comments_link').live('click', function() {

  if(e.handled !== true) // This will prevent event firing more than one time
  {
    e.handled = true;
    // Your code here...
  }
});
```