# how to use ajax loader with SQL commands

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Hi, I had a project as Applicant and the user go through more tabs to submit his data, he add his resume beside the data, but when the data is inserted to the Database it take long time and the user may click more times and this lead to insert repeated data.

I suggested to use Ajax loader as a popup, but I didn't know the best solution for this issue as I need this loader wait till the data inserted to DB.

Comment: Are you asking how to prevent the user from repeatedly clicking on a submit button? Because your save function is taking some time to complete?

Comment: yes,so I need to use the loader for this issue

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6064279/96505) which shows how to set a variable to see whether a request is currently running. That way you can temporarily disable the click function, while your process runs and then enable it when everything is done.

**Edit**
I've adapted the jQuery code from the above link to show how you *might* do what you need. The functions will need filling out with your own implementations. I wasn't able to do that for you - I don't know the structure of your current code...

```
var requestRunning = false;
$('#save_link').live('click', function () {
if (requestRunning) { // don't do anything if an AJAX request is pending
    return;
}

$(".save_link").text("Saving ...");

var ajaxOpts = {
    type: "",
    url: "", 
    dataType: "",
    data: "",
    success: function (data) {
        // something to show the user a save is happening maybe?
    },
    complete: function() {
        requestRunning = false;
    }

};

requestRunning = true;
$.ajax(ajaxOpts);
return false;
});
```