# Prevent jQuery function from running while request is running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I need to reuse often. The problem occurs when I load another page into the current page, the function fires twice. I tried this solution but could not get it to work ([Disable jquery function after 1 click, to prevent multiple executions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064232/disable-jquery-function-after-1-click-to-prevent-multiple-executions)). Any solutions to prevent the function from firing multiple times while a request is being made? The function should only fire once per click.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.likeclick = function(thiss, key) {  
        var $this = thiss;
        var pid=key;
        if ($this.hasClass('addd')) {
            $.post("/blah.php?id="+pid, function(data) {
                if (data=="ok"){
                    $this.removeClass('addd').addClass('rem');
                    $('.ccount#'+pid).html(function(i,val) {
                        return (parseFloat(val) + 1).toFixed(0);
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            $.post("/blah1.php?id="+pid, function(data) {
                if (data=="okk"){
                    $this.removeClass('rem').addClass('addd');
                    $('.ccount#'+pid).html(function(i,val) {
                        return (parseFloat(val) - 1).toFixed(0);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
<div class="like addd"></div>

$('.like').click(function() {
    likeclick($(this),this.id);
});
```

Comment: What happened when you tried the technique in the linked question?  It looks as though it should work for your case.

Comment: "load another page into the current page" - meaning some sort of ajax get? if so, what do you do after the ajax request? it would be easier if you posted all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, what you need is a way for the function to know that if there is currently any active requests before making its request. Why not add a boolean like `hasActiveRequest` to keep track of this? So by default its `false`, then when they click it, check that boolean...if false then set it to `true` and make the request; else if its `true`, then don't make request (since there is already one in progress). When the request is complete, then set the boolean back to `false`.

Comment: could you show me where to put the booleans. I know what you're talking about (if (hasActiveRequest) return false;) but I can't figure out where to put them in the code

Comment: You could just define `var hasActiveRequest = false; ` at the top, add the line just before `$.fn.likeclick = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Since the functions did not work on the pages (or data) that were loaded with the .post() method, I tried adding the jQuery function to the loaded page directly or with a .js file. Either way the code was being executed multiple times after a few pages were loaded using .post(). Whether I used delays, timeout functions or added booleans to try to prevent the function from being fired multiple times per click, the function still executed multiple times.

After an endless search I came across this article (http://docs.jquery.com/FAQ#Why_do_my_events_stop_working_after_an_AJAX_request.3F) in the jQuery documentation.

In that article it states:

> Beware! As of jQuery 1.4.2, binding the same handler to the same
>   element multiple times will cause it to execute more than once. This
>   differs from previous versions of jQuery as well as the DOM 2 Events
>   spec (which normally ignores duplicate event handlers).

More research turned up the .live() method, but that method is deprecated. The .on() method replaced .live(). So my solution is:

```
$(document).on('click', '.like', function(){
var $this = $(this);
likeclick($this,this.id);
});
```

Now I don't have to add functions to the loaded page (data) from the .post() method or use other methods to try and prevent the function from firing twice.