# Can clicking too fast skip some operations in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile app displaying a list of items. I can select an item and move it up or down when clicking an up or down button.

When I move an item up or down by clicking the button the displayed items are swapped as well as their item-id. Then I send an ajax post message with the step moved by the item.

What I have seen is that if I click too fast, sometime the item doesn't move all the expected way. It may also happen that the item-id becomes duplicated as if the function has been interrupted in the middle of the item-id swapping operation.

Is this a known feature ? Is there a solution to avoid this ?

Here is the code to move the items

```
$("#btnListUp").on( "click", function(evt)
{
    if( selectedItem && !selectedItem.hasClass('ui-first-child') )
    {
        var prev = selectedItem.prev();
        var prevId = prev.attr('item-id');
        var thisId = selectedItem.attr('item-id');
        var step = (parseInt(prevId) - parseInt(thisId))+'';
        prev.attr('item-id', thisId );
        selectedItem.attr('item-id', prevId );
        prev.detach().insertAfter(selectedItem);
        $('#ShopList').listview('refresh');
        $.ajax( {type: 'POST', url: thisId+'/moveUp', data : step,
                contentType :'applicatio/octet-stream' } );
    }
});

$("#btnListDown").on( "click", function(evt)
{
    if( selectedItem && !selectedItem.hasClass('ui-last-child') )
    {
        var next = selectedItem.next();
        var nextId = next.attr('item-id');
        var thisId = selectedItem.attr('item-id');
        var step = (parseInt(nextId) - parseInt(thisId))+'';
        next.attr('item-id', thisId );
        selectedItem.attr('item-id', nextId );
        next.detach().insertBefore(selectedItem);
        $('#ShopList').listview('refresh');
        $.ajax( {type: 'POST', url: thisId+'/moveDown', data : step,
                contentType :'applicatio/octet-stream' } );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected outcome, you have click event bound to the btnListUp and btnListDown elements. Next click event is not going to wait for the first one to finish, nor will first one postpone the second one.

In your case only two solution are possible.

### Solution 1

First, after the first click, unbound the click event from the button, like this:

```
$("#btnListUp").on( "click", function(evt)
{
    $(this).off('click');
```

Second, during the ajax success and error callback bind the click event again. This is one way.

### Solution 2

Second solution is an easier one but sometimes you will no be able to use it:

Take a look at this link:

[Disable jquery function after 1 click, to prevent multiple executions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064232/disable-jquery-function-after-1-click-to-prevent-multiple-executions)

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I need to disable the up and down button at the same time. I don't need to wait for the ajax completion to enable it again. Programming with asynchronous execution needs more attention than I thought. I thought the functions execution of two "overlapping" clicks would be queued. But apparently they aren't. How would you rebind the function ? I guess I need to define the function outside of the first on() then.

Comment: In your case first try to implement solution 2. It is much easier solution and it will require small changes. If it fails I will write you an example of solution 1.

Comment: Well I just tried solution 1 which looked more simple to me. I set back the on("click") just after the ajax call, thus not waiting for its completion. I did this to avoid the network latency. I thought the ajax calls would be queued. The problem I see is that the database is not properly updated.

Comment: There is a problem in my code because I send an ajax message with the item-Id are item reference and this is swapped in the reordering process. So the item reference is relative to the execution order. If the ajax calls are reordered, the result is bogus. I see that adding a single variable stating that the op is in progress could do the trick and is much simpler than unbind and rebind the function.

Comment: That is why I proposed it as an easier solution.

Comment: Apparently the problem is cause by database operations performed concurrently on the server side. This is because I use uWSGI which runs multiple process in parallel. This doesn't work well with sqlite which doesn't support concurrent access (out of the box). Your solution enforcing serialization of all requests to the server will solve it, but I would like to avoid it and try to take advantage of the pipelining capability of the network. So I'm migrating to postgresql. But an additional complexity that comes with it is that ops may arrive to the DB in a different order they were emitted.

Comment: Solving the out of order processing of multiple ops coming from a browser (fast click sequence) while preserving asynchronous processing for ops allowing it, requires to serialize ops sent to the server. The solution is to queue ops to be sent to the server while ajax is busy. This doesn't solve the concurrency from different browsers, but such types of collisions are much less probable. The add operation can't be asynchronous because it gets back the item id assigned by the database to the new item. In this case all buttons clicks should have no effect. This is implemented with your method.