# Strange issues when adding/deleting items to an array on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I got a modal with a list of items.

Clicking the item div adds the item to the list, and also updates the cart total price.

Clicking the selected item removes the item from the list, and also updates the cart total price.

And it works great, when clicking slowly, but when I click like a maniac (add/delete many items in a short time period) I get strange results like: the selected value doesn't go back to 0, or some items are still in the 'itemsInBuyCart' array despite none of them being actually selected.

```
app.addItemToBuyCart = function(item, price, div) {
        if (app.addClicking) return;
        app.addClicking = 1;
        if (app.itemsInBuyCart.indexOf(item.toString()) == -1) {
            app.itemsInBuyCart.push(item.toString());
            div.children().addClass("selected");
              app.buySelectedValue += price;
        } else {
            app.itemsInBuyCart.splice(app.itemsInBuyCart.indexOf(item));
            div.children().removeClass("selected");
             app.buySelectedValue -= price;
        }
     $('#buySelectedValue').text(app.buySelectedValue);
        app.addClicking = 0;
    }
```

The clickable divs for each item are generated like this:

```
$("#buyCartModal").append('<div style="cursor:pointer" onClick="app.addItemToBuyCart(' + item.id + ', '+item.price+', $(this));"
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of logic with DOM manipulation that goes on here. This can be just taxing enough on performance, meaning rapid clicks aren't always registered because the previous function is still running (or weird behaviors like you've described come about).

**So what can you do about it?**

Without seeing your full code I can't make very helpful optimization recommendations, but as a general suggestion, set a boolean varaible that must be true in order for the function to be called via `onClick`. Set the boolean variable to true at the very end of `addItemToBuyCart()` and false at the very beginning. That's a little vague but I think you get the idea, and this ensures that you are only calling your function when the browser is ready to handle the request.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I still get some items as visually 'selected' when they arent in array, and I still get some items not visually 'selected' even if they are in array. This happens when I click too fast. Is there any solution other than iterate over the full list of items (there are thousands)? That is my full code you are seeing = ( I even tried replacing jquery addclass method with core javascript style change, and still the same behaviour.

Comment: Here's another SO question that looks at your problem: [Clicking too fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462013/can-clicking-too-fast-skip-some-operations-in-jquery-mobile) - 
Solution 1 might be worth a shot, but ultimately this behavior is difficult to avoid. When looking at solution 1, notice that `onClick` is not in the HTML, but rather in the JS. I would recommend making this change, because even if it doesn't work, it's generally the better programming practice.