# How to prevent other events calling js function based on some function using jquery

Tags: jquery

multiple selectors calling same jquery method on click event.

I've to prevent further calls to the method by other events based on some condition verified by first event call..

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064232/disable-jquery-function-after-1-click-to-prevent-multiple-executions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will disable the event handlers for all elements after any one of the elements has been clicked

```
$("#parent").on("click",".elementToClick",function(){
   $('#parent').off();
   // plus whatever else you need to do 
     });
```

Comment: TGH: it works really fine all duplicate calls..again if I try to click on same div nothing works...

Comment: Yes, all buttons are disabled if any one button is clicked - including the button that was initially clicked

Comment: Instead of removing the handler after firing it once, you could use [jQuery one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Comment: That will not prevent the other buttons from being clicked once as well though

Answer (score 0):

```
var once = false;
var myFunction = function(e){
  if(!once){
    once = true;
    // executed first time
  }else{
    // executed after first time
  }
}
$(selector).click(myFunction)
```