# Onclick event on button firing twice for one user only?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Apologies if the title seemed a bit vague, but I am at a complete loss as to why this may be happening now.

I have an online application that has been used for more than 2 years by a team of people, and we had a new starter about 6 months ago who when using the application, approx once a month, an event fires twice for this one user, and no other person.

It is a very basic onclick event the fires to controller, that updates a DB, I have tried to replicate the issue but am unable to on anyone else's machine.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="advanceJob()">Advance Job</button>


function advanceJob() {
var details = {
                Id: selectedJob,
                MovedOnBy: '@ViewBag.DisplayName',
                Frequency: $('#jobFrequency').val()
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Home/MoveJobOn',
                cache: false,
                data: details,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#jobModal').modal('hide');
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (x, y, z) {
                    alert(x.responseText + " " + y.responseText + " " + z.responseText);
                }
}
            });
```

I can only think it may be something specific to that persons machine, but have never encountered this before with any other of my applications.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's anything here to prevent a user double-clicking the button. Could it simply be that user is a double-clicker?

Comment: No, several of us have tried testing it, and it isnt possible to send the query twice by double clicking

Answer (score 0):

Try to test this event using different browsers, if they all click twice, perhaps the issue is the Mouse is broken, try to replace the new Mouse.

Besides, you could also refer to the following code to disable the button after fist click the button.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="advanceJob(this)">Advance Job</button>
<span id="output"></span>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var count = 0;
    function advanceJob(e) {
        $(e).attr("disabled", true);
        //after 3 seconds, enable the button.
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(e).removeAttr("disabled");
        }, 3000);
        count++;
        $("#output").html(count.toString());
        ////other actions
        //var details = {
        //    Id: selectedJob,
        //    MovedOnBy: '@ViewBag.DisplayName',
        //    Frequency: $('#jobFrequency').val()
        //}
        //$.ajax({
        //    type: 'POST',
        //    url: '/Home/MoveJobOn',
        //    cache: false,
        //    data: details,
        //    success: function (data) {
        //        $('#jobModal').modal('hide');
        //        alert(data);
        //    },
        //    error: function (x, y, z) {
        //        alert(x.responseText + " " + y.responseText + " " + z.responseText);
        //    }
        //}
    };
</script>
```

Also you could refer to this article to [prevent multiple click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064232/disable-jquery-function-after-1-click-to-prevent-multiple-executions) the button.

Comment: Its not a double click issue, the second record is entering the DB about 4/100 of a second after the first.

Comment: Try to use [F12 developer tools Network tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255004%28v%3dvs.85%29) to check whether it post two request, if it only submit once, you need to check the MoveJobOn method, try to add some debugger to debug the code.